# Get custom Section Class in Shopify from settings

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to get section class from settings? If so, how?

I couldn't find anything besides this dead end: https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Add-CSS-Class-to-a-Section/td-p/304526

I would assume that you can't from the same json that you're trying to create. Is there a way to schema.append() or something similar?

Comment: No. Just wondering why would you need that?

Comment: because your main section classes are in the schema. And if you want to change the background of the section dynamically, you can't.

Comment: Can you just assign the styles or class value from section settings to the wrapper element of the block with your code?